# Peel first, wash first, or don't peel at all vegetables?

Tags: vegetables, peeling

Which vegetables should be washed before peeling them? Which should be washed *after* peeling? Which can (and should) be eaten without peeling them? What is the logic behind this?

Comment: Have you ever dug out some potatoes? That should give you a first clue. All packaged grocery store veggies are washed.

Comment: @Johannes_B if my mushrooms are washed, they're very badly washed - but I doubt they are

Comment: @Johannes_B Please do not use comments to answer questions. This is not how they are meant to be used in SE.

Comment: @Chris Good point, would be a bad idea to wash them.

Comment: I'm going to say this depends on personal preference and also the specific recipe. I think that makes it too broad/opinion based for this site. For example, I like to peel my potatoes to make mashed potatoes, but almost never peel them if I'm roasting them.

Answer (score 1):

Wash/rinse before peeling or eating the produce, especially if wanting to eat the skin (for example apples...)

It'll help reduce the risk of contaminating the flesh of the produce with residual pesticides (and other contaminants like dirt).

Some vegetables like potatoes can be rinsed after peeling to remove some of the starch, you can also rinse onions to remove some of the "raw-ness" when wanting to eat the onion raw

It depends on the final application/recipe.

Answer (score 1):

Just a personal preference, nothing scientific going on in my answer. But I like to keep the skin as much as possible, so the key for me is to use a **veggies brush**, and I scrub them hard as I'm washing.